# devenv.exe - Application Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devenv

I'm trying to install Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and I'm getting the following error.

```
devenv.exe - Application Error

The instruction at 0x7707bebe referenced memory at 0x7714ffff. 
The memory could not be read.

Click on OK to terminate the program
Click on CANCEL to debug the program
```

Clicking on any of them is closing Visual Studio & I cannot move forward.

I tried restarting the system, uninstall & re installing VS package. Both of them didn't change the error.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to get your machine stable again before you try this.  That requires the geek squad, not a programmer.

Comment: @HansPassant - I googled around and found a few solutions & none of them worked for my case. thanks for your reply, I will contact IT support.